# Exclusions in NIntegrate automatically uses GlobalAdaptive method?

Tags: numerical-integration

I tried to integrate a function using `LocalAdaptive` method. However, if I add `Exclusions` option  in addition to `LocalAdaptive` method, I suspect that Mathematica automatically (and silently) changes to `GlobalAdaptive` method. I saw this behavior by the following example:

```
Needs["Integration`NIntegrateUtilities`"]
exp = Exp[I k x]/x^a Exp[I/x - x]
```

First, I performed the integration using pure `LocalAdaptive` method, and obtained where Mathematica sampled points:

```
NIntegrateSamplingPoints@
 NIntegrate[exp /. {a -> 1/4, k -> 10}, {x, 0, 10}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive", 
  IntegrationMonitor :> ((errors = Through[#1@"Error"]) &)]
```

[image]

If we add `Exclusions` option as follows, the behavior totally changes!

```
NIntegrateSamplingPoints@
 NIntegrate[exp /. {a -> 1/4, k -> 10}, {x, 0, 10}, 
  Exclusions -> x == 0, Method -> "LocalAdaptive", 
  IntegrationMonitor :> ((errors = Through[#1@"Error"]) &)]
```

[image]

Curiously, this is the same when I use `GlobalAdaptive` method!:

```
NIntegrateSamplingPoints@
 NIntegrate[exp /. {a -> 1/4, k -> 10}, {x, 0, 10},  
  Exclusions -> x == 0, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive", 
  IntegrationMonitor :> ((errors = Through[#1@"Error"]) &)]
```

[image]

What happened? Is this behavior general?

Comment: Side issue, probably unrelated: Use `Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}` with `Exclusions` and we seem to run into a method-parsing bug. (Compare with `Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 1}` or without `Exclusions`). Also fails with `Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}`.  Must be an incompatibility of `Exclusions` and no symbolic processing.

Comment: `Exclusions -> x == 0` causes the Levin Rule to be invoked. It overrides `Method -> "NewtonCotesRule"` and perhaps every method spec. I cannot explain why at this point. `Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0, Method -> "LevinRule"}` shows that the Levin Rule is incompatible with `"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0` in agreement with my previous comment. (It makes sense to a certain degree, but the error messages could and should be clearer.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, as always! This is very curious.

Comment: Have you ever regarded the integrand `exp /. {a -> 1/4, k -> 10} ` ?  ComplexExpanded you get `(E^-x Cos[1/x + 10 x])/x^(1/4) + (I E^-x Sin[1/x + 10 x])/x^(1/4) ` which shows, for x -> 0, integrand goes to infinity with infinte more and more oscillations. `LogLogPlot[(E^-x Cos[1/x + 10 x])/x^(1/4), {x, 10^-5, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {10^-1, 2 10^1}, PlotPoints -> 1000] `   No NIntegrate can do that.

Comment: @Akku14 Yes, but one can mathematically show that my function is integrable, both in Lebesgue sense and improper Riemann integral sense.